# Thrust vector of structs containing pointers

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have the following data structure:

```
struct Data {
    int* ptr;
    int a;
    int b;
}
```

I need an array of such structures on the GPU passed from the host. The easy way to do that is

```
thrust::host_vector<Data> h;
... // fill vector 'h'
thrust::device_vector<Data> d = h;
```

The tricky moment is how to allocate the memory for `ptr` and how to copy data there. Is there any suggestions?

Comment: Pointers can be copied just like other values, but presumably you want to dereference pointers in GPU code.  The right way to transfer data depends on what you are doing with the pointers.   What does `ptr` point to?  Is the data read or written on the GPU?  Is it possible that several instances of `Data` contain pointers to the same object?

Comment: @Heatsink: `ptr` is a pointer to the device memory individual for each `Data` object. I just now realized that I can write something like `cudaMalloc( &h[i].ptr,...)` and later assign `d=h`. Is it true? I can't say why it was confusing me before. ) Do you want to get the accepted answer? Please, formulate your comment as an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated** based on your comment to @Heatsink, if I understand correctly you're saying that  given

```
struct Data {
    int* ptr;
    int a, b;
};
```

and

```
vector<Data> data;
```

`data[0].ptr` points to GPU memory containing `data[0].a` and `data[0].b` If this is correct, then I would recommend the following organization instead:

```
struct Data {
    int a, b;
};

thrust::host_vector<Data> h;
thrust::device_vector<Data> d = h;
```

The GPU memory for `h[i]` is simply `d[i]`. I would not recommend storing a pointer per-element to the GPU memory, nor would you want to allocate separate GPU memory for each data object (would be horrifically slow.) Your compute code will still probably be faster if you use separate arrays as well.

Generally organizing your data as structure-of-arrays instead of array-of-structures is preferred for several reasons, including alignment and ease of load coalescing.

Comment: With respect to my problem, it is known that each block will access only 1 element of an array so I can sacrifice the universality to the code clarity )

Comment: @AdelNick I updated my answer to reflect the clarification you provided to Heatsink above.

Comment: no, `ptr` does not store `a` and `b`. It is the separate independent piece of memory, so for each `Data` object I need to allocate memory for `ptr` and fill it with the data and also assign the values for `a` and `b`.

Comment: @AdelNick some information about how much data is stored in ptr and where it comes from would be useful then. My comment about not wanting to separately allocate device memory for each Data object still stands.